# Access fragment variable outside of Fragment in view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZuxy.png)

Before reading the question, please refer to image.

I am using viewpager to show the fragment.

**Problem**

In the fragment, I have used two edittext lets say editText1, editText2 now the problem is  how I will get the editText data. I can only get the editText values when user click on next button but the next button is outside of fragment. How do I access the editText outside the fragment.

Before downvoting the question, let me know the reason so that I can improve my question.

Fragment java class

```
// newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
        public static BpDetails newInstance(int page) {
            BpDetails fragmentFirst = new BpDetails();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("someInt", page);
            fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
            return fragmentFirst;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
        }


        // Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bp_details, container, false);

            Log.i("View ",view.toString());

            Log.i("DOB is ",Long.toString(Constants.dob));


            systolic =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.systolic);
            diastolic =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.diastolic);


            return view;
        }
```

ViewPager Activity

```
vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

        Fragment fragment=adapterViewPager.getItem(prevPage);

        if (fragment.getClass().equals(BpDetails.class)){
            Log.i("Call ","Yes");
        }

        findViewById(R.id.btn_prev).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // checking for last page
                // if last page home screen will be launched
                int current = getItem(-1);
                if (current!=0)
                    prevPage=current-1;
                if (current < 4) {
                    // move to next screen
                    vpPager.setCurrentItem(current);
                } else {
                    //final reached.
                }

            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.btn_next).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // checking for last page
                // if last page home screen will be launched
                int current = getItem(+1);



                if (current!=0)
                    prevPage=current-1;

                System.out.println("Prev page "+prevPage);

                if (current < 4) {
                    // move to next screen

                    Fragment prevFragment=adapterViewPager.getItem(prevPage);


                } else {

                    //final reached.
                }
            }
        });


    }

    private int getItem(int i) {
        return vpPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }


    public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private static int NUM_ITEMS = 4;
        private static int mSelectedPosition;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
            //mSelectedPosition=selectedPosition;
        }

        // Returns total number of pages
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        // Returns the fragment to display for that page
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                    return BasicDetails.newInstance(0);
                case 1:
                    return BpDetails.newInstance(1);
                case 2:
                    return BslDetails.newInstance(2);
                case 3:
                    return Summary.newInstance(3);

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: ^. How are you implementing the `ViewPager`

Comment: @an_droid_dev shared the code.

Comment: @JoshLaird I have shared the code.

Answer (score 0):

Create two getters inside your fragment like this.

```
public String getSystolic(){

    return this.systolic.getText().toString();

    }

public String getDiastolic(){

    return this.diastolic.getText().toString();
    }



     BpDetails fr = (BpDetails)myAdapter.getItem(myViewPager.getCurrentItem());
     String systolicString = fr.getSystolic();
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference this is error I am getting. I am calling      BpDetails fr = (BpDetails)myAdapter.getItem(myViewPager.getCurrentItem());
     String systolicString = fr.getSystolic();
 this , on click on next button.

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal put a breakpoint into onCreateView method or log and look if your EditText is null

Comment: I have put the log in fragment, the edittext is not null.

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal this fragment is visible in viewpager when you click "next" button?

Comment: Yes. @an_droid. Fragment is visible. I click on next button and then app get crash.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. `.getItem()` instantiates a new `Fragment`, so upon calling `myAdapter.getItem(...)` you would be getting null for all elements in the `Fragment`, but not null for the `Fragment`.

When I fixed this, what I had to do was create another method inside of `MyPagerAdapter` called `getInstantiatedFragment`:

```
public Fragment getInstantiatedFragment(int position)
    {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }
```

`fragments` is a new field for the class:

```
private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
```

I would override `getItem()` (as you have done already) and change it to:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                BasicDetails basicDetails = BasicDetails.newInstance(0);
                fragments.add(basicDetails);
                return basicDetails;
            ...
    }
```

where you're adding the fragment to `fragments` before returning, then you would call:

```
BpDetails fr = (BpDetails)myAdapter.getInstantiatedItem(myViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

to get the instance of the created fragment and then call

`String systolicString = fr.getSystolic();`

if you're using the previous answer's method.

This is so that you can keep track of the instantiated fragments in `fragments`. I'm sure there are better ways.

Comment: You shouldn't do that because you will keep strong reference to Fragment instances. Moreover, `FragmentPagerAdapter ` already caches `Fragments` for you.  `get(int position)` is only being called in case, if the fragment was not found in cache.

Comment: I agree, however `getItem(...)` would never get the instantiated `Fragment`s for me, it would always create a new one. It seems like it's an abstract method in [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java) so this would explain why it's instantiating a new `Fragment` each time, no?

Comment: Well, if you take a look on implementation of `FragmentPagerAdapter` you will see that `getItem(...)` is called during instantiating of items.  However, before it gets called, FPA tries to find such a fragment in its "cache" using `findFragmentByTag` and only if result is `null`, then it is your responsibility to provide new instance of such a fragment. Hence `getItem` is wont get called when you rotate device for example

Comment: I have call this function BpDetails fr = (BpDetails)myAdapter.getInstantiatedItem(myViewPager.getCurrentItem());
when user click on next button but then getInstantiatedItem() is unidentified. @JoshLaird